# does <context:annotation-config /> handles HTTP requests

Tags: java, xml, spring

I am building a web application on Spring.

I am confused whether I should use  **mvc:annotation-driven** or   **context:annotation-config**  in configuration to scan annotations to handle HTTP requests?

Answer (score 1):

No, despite the confusingly similar keywords, `annotation-config` does not handle HTTP requests. For handling HTTP requests you only need mvc:annotation-driven.

- `context:annotation-config` causes Java Configuration classes with `@Configuration` annotation to be loaded. See [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config)
- `mvc:annotation-driven` causes Spring to wire up any `@RequestMapping`, `@Controller` annotations etc. See [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **mvc:annotation-driven**.

The first link will explain what **mvc:annotation-driven** does and the second link what **context:annotation-config** does

1. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable
2. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config